# ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que se empujen a otros elementos cuando utilizamos la propieda position?

Tags: html5, css3, position

Estoy dándole vueltas a la propiedad position del CSS y me surge una pregunta. ¿Existe alguna manera de hacer que posicionemos un elemento con la propiedad position y la propiedad top, y que este elemento empuje a su vez a los que tiene por detrás?

En teoría no, porque se sale del flujo del HTML. Pero entonces, ¿Qué utilidad tiene? ¿En qué casos se salen los elementos del flujo de HTML y cómo interactúan entre ellos si hay varios que se han salido?

Os dejo un ejemplo de prueba:

```
style.css

.padre{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.hijo1{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
}

.hijo2{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 160px;
}

.hijo3{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 320px;*/
}
```

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="padre">
      <div class="hijo1">Box 1</div>
      <div class="hijo2">Box 2</div>
      <div class="hijo3">Box 3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias,

Comment: ¿Qué utilidad tiene?, como posicionas un pseudoelemento sobre un elemento?, Como plotas un boton de chat al final de tu dom?, Como podría hacer efectos de posicionamiento y animaciones css sin relative y absolute? y asi podría hacer mil preguntas sobre position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca un elemento elemento con `position: absolute` va a empujar a otros elementos.

Cuando utilizes esta propiedad en elementos hermanos estos se posicionarán uno sobre otro en el mismo orden en que están escrito el HTML, para cambiar ese orden existe la propiedad de CSS `z-index`.

Es común que en ciertas ocaciones sea necesario posicionar un elemento sobre otro por ejemplo un tooltip o modales, en esos casos es muy util entender las posiciones.